# MIPS wired logic DPU

Tags: assembly, logic, mips, risc, micro-architecture

I am a student and i have an exercise on MIPS and i need some guidance! Below is the exercise:

Consider the Data Processing Unit of MIPS architecture wired logic for a command cycle for single and multiple machine cycles. Describe the full flow of information and
in both implementation cases - single and multiple machine cycles - for the command:
bne $ 12, $ 4, -100
where -100 is the displacement of relative addressing commands.
In particular, report all the values ​​of the control signals produced, as well as the
micro-processes performed in each DPU, in the order in which they are executed, whether useful for the mandate or not - which is requested
to report. Also, write the information values ​​that arrive at each subunit
and each multiplexer. Finally, in the case of multiple machine cycles, please report
the registers of the A, B, C, IR and DR registers occurring, as well as the values
are recorded.
Consider that the $ 12 and $ 4 registers contain the values ​​at the beginning of the instruction cycle
8 and 0 respectively, while the PC contains the address 0x1480a008.
How would the execution of the above command evolve if the $ 4 registrar is in the beginning
of the command cycle contained the value of 8;

Thanks...

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. We're not going to write code for you, but if you show us what you've tried so far and explain how it is failing or behaving in ways that are unexpected, we would be happy to help out.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! I am not asking for any code.  Im having problem with this and wanted some guidance as i said already! Any helpful and useful  comment is welcome!